# How to install dependencies on CLI command line with this error?

Tags: node.js, command-line, dependencies, twilio, watson-conversation

What does it mean when I receive this error when I execute the following command...

**C:\Users\dnort\Desktop\sms-bot-master>npm install botkit-middleware-watson --save**

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dnort\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-12-19T12_24_42_335Z-debug.log

**C:\Users\dnort\Desktop\sms-bot-master>npm install botkit-sms --save**

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dnort\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-12-19T12_26_04_918Z-debug.log

[here's the log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrenN.jpg)

Comment: What is in the log file...?

Comment: @data_henrik ive embedded it in the question

Comment: Are you using npm behind a proxy here?